# ConnectionRefused trying to do HttpGet in Android

Tags: android, http

I am trying to do a simple HttpGet but it isn't even getting outside the App space as nothing comes up in Fiddler.

```
private final static String EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI = "http://localhost:82/EmployeeService_deploy/EmployeeInfo.svc/GetEmployee/?key=";  

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI + "11");

        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        //get the response
        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I have a feeling it might be because my work has a firewall and this is on port 82. I had thought because it's HTTP though it might allow it but possibly not. In the manifest I have the following permissions

<

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />       
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what else this could be and how I can get around it? I do not have access to my works proxy settings so if that is the issue I cannot specify a proxy. Is there any way I can route it through port 80?

```
05-30 06:32:34.890: W/System.err(1617): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:82 refused
05-30 06:32:34.890: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
05-30 06:32:34.920: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-30 06:32:34.920: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-30 06:32:34.940: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-30 06:32:34.940: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at lakecrest.tayle.network.tasks.GetData.doInBackground(GetData.java:65)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at lakecrest.tayle.network.tasks.GetData.doInBackground(GetData.java:1)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-30 06:32:34.950: W/System.err(1617):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-30 06:32:34.980: W/System.err(1617):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-30 06:32:34.980: W/System.err(1617): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 82): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
05-30 06:32:34.980: W/System.err(1617):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
05-30 06:32:34.980: W/System.err(1617):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-30 06:32:34.980: W/System.err(1617):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-30 06:32:34.980: W/System.err(1617):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
05-30 06:32:35.020: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-30 06:32:35.020: W/System.err(1617):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
05-30 06:32:35.030: W/System.err(1617):     ... 14 more
05-30 06:32:35.040: W/System.err(1617): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
05-30 06:32:35.050: W/System.err(1617):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
05-30 06:32:35.050: W/System.err(1617):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
05-30 06:32:35.080: W/System.err(1617):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-30 06:32:35.080: W/System.err(1617):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-30 06:32:35.090: W/System.err(1617):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: Did you try doing that in an Async Block?

Comment: Yes, the method this is called in is protected ArrayList<DbItem> doInBackground(String... params), in a class that extends AsyncTask

Comment: Add logcat log please

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845060/connection-to-http-10-0-2-2-refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app running on an emulator or on a device? And where runs fiddler? If you want to use 127.0.0.1 then they should both be on one emulatof or both on the same device.

Comment: My app is running on the AVD emulator packaged with Eclipse which is running locally on my machine and my web service is running on IIS locally on my machine. Fiddler runs locally on my machine too. So are you saying the Emulator does not recognise localhost as the same localhost that fiddler/IIS do? How do I configure Emulator to find the processes running locally on my machine?

Comment: Localhost(127.0.01) for an app on the emulator is a server running on the same emulator. Use 10.0.2.2 as ip address if an app on the emulator wants to connect to a server that is running on the same pc as the emulator. You do not have to configer the emulator. Your client app should use that ip.

Comment: So change IIS to host the website as http://10.0.2.2:82 - and I then set that as the connection string on the app aswell, not localhost? What is the significance of 10.0.2.2?

Comment: No you don't change anything with IIS. Just let your client app use 10.0.2.2. That's all. The significance? Thats how googgle decided how to forward requests from emulator to pc.

Answer (score 0):

Use async task to use HTTP calls.

```
private class HttpCalling extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String resp;
        //HTTP calls here
        return resp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```